# Detect whether there is a spatial polygon in a spatial extent

Tags: raster, r

Given a spatial extent (for example `cbind(c(0,0),c(10,10)`), I want to see whether there is a part of a SpatialPolygons falls in this extent?

How can I do this?

Comment: How is your polygon represented?  If it's in vector format, just clip the polygon to the extent and see whether the result is nonempty.  Many spatial libraries implement clipping. One that is specialized to the task is at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gpclib/index.html.

Comment: I think clipping can do this, but if I have a lot of zones to process?

Comment: Is a "zone" a polygon or an extent?  Many clipping functions will clip a collection of polygons *en masse* to a single rectangle: this is a fundamental operation for displaying polygons within a rectangular window, so there exist heavily optimized solutions.

Comment: I will consider it as an extent. So do you have some suggestions on methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bbox(spatialpolygons)` will give you the bounding box of a spatialpolygons object. You just need to test if any of the bounds are outside your extent with four greater-than or less-than tests. There's no need to do any clipping.

Never use `gpclib` - it has a restrictive license. When you do want to do polygon clipping and buffering and all those groovy GIS things, use `rgeos`.

Comment: Are you claiming that when the extent of a polygon intersects a given extent, then the polygon itself intersects that extent?  That's what your first paragraph appears to say.

Comment: The OP asked if a polygon falls in (which I understand to mean 'is wholly contained in') an extent. For polygon A to be wholly contained in the rectangular axis-aligned box B it is sufficient to test each of the four bounds of A as being less than those of B. If any of the bounds are larger then part of the polygon must necessarily be outside of B.

Comment: Your understanding of "falls in" is an important qualification to include in your answer, so that others do not misinterpret it!

Comment: Agreed, and I see the ambiguity now. I would explicitly say "test if -any part- of a spatial polygons falls in an extent" to get the other possibility. An unqualified "falls in" to me means completely enclosed by. You can only "fall in" to a hole if all of you falls in :)

Comment: I think it makes sense, my concern is how to perform spatial query in R.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on spacedman's suggestion, here is how you can get the intersection of two extents (NULL if not intersecting). 'sp' is a Spatial* object

```
library(raster)
e <- extent(c(0,10,0,10))
intersect(e, extent(sp))
```

But it may indeed be, as whuber points out, that the polygon is in fact not inside extent e. If you need to know that, do

```
library(rgeos)
gIntersects(as(e, 'SpatialPolygons'), sp)
```

For large problems, it may be efficient to do

```
in <- intersect(e, extent(sp))
if (isTRUE(in)) { in <- gIntersects(as(e, 'SpatialPolygons'), sp) }
```